# MS- Access VBA Converting multiple characters to Asc

Tags: vba, ms-access

For a homework project I am trying to enter characters in a single textbox as (eg:"AbC" no spaces) and have the output in a captioned label as the corresponding ASCII value written out with commas and spaces. (eg: 65, 98, 67)

```
Private Sub cmdCode_Click()
Dim codeInt As Integer
strInput = txtInput.value
codeInt = Asc(strInput)
lblAnswer.Caption = codeInt & ", "
End Sub
```

I would like the result to look like: 65, 98, 67

I'm getting no errors but only receiving "65," as my output.

Comment: If this is a homework, what are your researches? Do you have any idea what's happening? We will not solve your homework, but will be glad if you learn something.

Comment: My researches got me this far as I have never worked with separating each character from a single input. I had a 3 minute tutorial from a teacher learning how to use Left, mid, right, Lcase and Ucase and got homework that had nothing to do with any of those functions. Thus, I have been working on this project for literally 12 hours and this is the last thing I'm stuck on. I just need to know how to put spaces in the output.

Comment: Options: 1. parse the string elements to an array and loop the array 2. use Mid() string manipulation function and integer variable, increment the variable in a loop to use in the Mid() function to select character at position designated by the integer value. In either case, within loop concatenate variables and literal characters: `strOut = strOut & ", " & strASC

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what researches are? Are we referring where I have already looked for the answer? If that's the case I have read almost the whole Mastering VBA book, researched all the previous tutorials, searched the internet and stack overflow extensively. Our teacher is no help and the other students don't participate.

Comment: @June7 Thank you! This helps. So glad there are people like you around.

Comment: Did edits on my comment.

Comment: Jamie, did you already wrote a pseudocode?
Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? (not in code, in your own words)

Comment: Obviously my college education is not worth what I'm paying for it because I  had never heard of a pseudocode until this moment because the concept has never been introduced. It's my first year of coding, first coding class besides powershell. So the answer is no, I don't have any idea how to write a pseudocode, but I will go ahead and research that.

Comment: I figured it out. `code`Private Sub cmdCode_Click()
Dim x As String
Dim y As String
Dim z As String
strInput = txtInput.value
x = Asc(Left(strInput, 1))
y = Asc(Mid(strInput, 2, 1))
z = Asc(Right(strInput, 1))
lblAnswer.Caption = x & ", " & y & ", " & z
End Sub `code`

Comment: @JamieSmith - Thanks for the update with your solution. Here on Stack Overflow it is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question, so please consider posting your code as an answer. **(1)** It will indicate that your issue has been resolved, and **(2)** you may earn some rep if your answer gains upvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done for generic usage - and a little smarter:

```
Public Function StrToAscList( _
    ByVal Text As String) _
    As String

    Dim Chars() As Byte
    Dim Item    As Integer
    Dim List    As String

    Chars() = StrConv(Text, vbFromUnicode)
    For Item = LBound(Chars) To UBound(Chars)
        If Item > 0 Then List = List & ", "
        List = List & CStr(Chars(Item))
    Next

    StrToAscList = List

End Function
```

Then:

```
Me!lblAnswer.Caption = StrToAscList(strInput)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. It assumes that the input is always going to be three (3) characters long:

```
Private Sub cmdCode_Click()
Dim x As String
Dim y As String
Dim z As String
strInput = txtInput.value
x = Asc(Left(strInput, 1))
y = Asc(Mid(strInput, 2, 1))
z = Asc(Right(strInput, 1))
lblAnswer.Caption = x & ", " & y & ", " & z
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a good start. You can generalize it to strings of any length by using `Mid(strInput, i, 1)` with `i` being the running variable in a `for` loop.

Comment: You can generalize it even further by creating a function that takes an input string, then uses the for loop, and returns an output string, allowing you to use that function anywhere in your project, and not only for these specific textboxes

Comment: Good to know that you are learning instead of coming only to get your homework done. In this site you can find a guide to how to write a pseudocode. https://www.wikihow.com/Write-Pseudocode